# creating a dataset in R

Tags: r, dataset

I would like to create a dataset in R with 1767 observations of value '1'. I know that I can create an empty dataset using data.frame but I dont know how can I fill it in with value 1 for 1767 times repeated.

what is a good way to have a dataset with 1 variable and 1767 observation of value 1?

Thanks!

Comment: See `?rep`. `mydf <- data.frame(v1=rep(1, 1767))` to be precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(myVar = rep(1L, 1767))
```